# Custom 404 page errors for .aspx extensions

Tags: asp.net, .net, http-status-code-404, episerver

I have been trying to have my web app to redirect to a custom 404 page. It works for all urls except if they have a ".aspx" extension

The server is a Windows Server 2008 and here are the following settings I have in my web.config (using google.com as a quick example):

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://www.google.com" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"></customErrors>

<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
<clear />
<remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
<error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404-Page/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
<error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404-Page/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Again the HTTP Errors work for everything but extensions of ".aspx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to solve this issue, we ended up having to create a module that hijacks any errors and transfers the user to my custom 404 page that is set in the web.config (under `customErrors`). The module would add an event handler to whenever the application gets an error:

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler(FileNotFound_Error);
    }
```

And the function `FileNoteFound_Error` does the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The `customErrors` element provides information about custom error messages for an ASP.NET application. Try adding a `error` child element to the `customErrors` element for the specific HTTP error code you want to trap.

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="error404.htm"/>
```

Comment: What does happen when you enter a URL in your browser for a .aspx file that doesn't exsist?

Comment: Just goes to the regular ASP error page rather then my custom page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in IIS6. I ended up handling it in Application_Error in global.asax. To make it work I had to set the 404 custom page to an aspx page that didn't exist (if I set it to an existing aspx page it would get swallowed up by EPiServer's internal error handling...)